# jQuery matchHeight - ignore an element

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, height

I use jQuery [matchHeight](http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/). It's used to make all elements in a row the same height.

Let's say I have two elements, `.main` and `.sidebar`. Sidebar should match height of Main but not the other way around. To be clear, Main should not match Sidebar.

I could do it with just `jQuery` but I use `matchHeight` on other places and it takes account for `padding`, `margin`, `box-sizing` and so on.

Is it possible? How?

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.match').matchHeight();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="main match">Main content</div>
<div class="sidebar match">Sidebar content</div>
```

**Update - Example**

- If .main is 345px and .sidebar is 1255px, then .main height should NOT be changed.
- If .sidebar is 345px and .main is 1255px, then .sidebar should be changed.

Main should never be changed. Sidebar should be changed if it's shorter than Main.

Comment: You want `.sidebar` to match `.main`, but `.main` to not match `.sidebar`? You might need to explain this a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the documentation on GitHub, you can set the options like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.sidebar').matchHeight({
        target: $('.main'),
        property: 'min-height'
    });
});
```

The above will set the min-height of `.sidebar` to be equal to the height of `.main` but not vise-versa